# Acceleration of falling body in regards to height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity

A boulder falls from a cliff of unknown height. Unfortunately, the stop-watch was in my back pocket, so I could only measure the time the boulder took to fall the final third of its journey, which was t=1.3s. How high is the cliff?

I could not work out this problem as I had trouble expressing the height as a variable to the time? Wrong approach perhaps?

Comment: Without knowing your approach we cannot see if your approach was 'wrong'...

Comment: If you know a third of its journey then you just multiply the time by 3 and you have the whole journey time, basic Suvat will give you the answer.

Comment: Hi Wangi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @Wangi Papa-I used conservation of energy and obtained 2 answers: 251 m and 2.561 m.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a simpler method, which I guess there must be, but I post mine here.

Consider only the last third of the boulders journey. If so, it doesn't start with a zero velocity, but a velocity which it has gained in the two third of its journey it has finished. Considering the total height $\ h $, the velocity gained would be given as $\ v^2 = 2 g (\frac {2 h}{3}) $ from $\ v^2 - u^2 = 2aS $. $\ S$ here is the distance covered i.e.$\ \frac {2h}{3}$

This value of velocity can be used in the $\ S = ut + \frac {1}{2}at^2 $ equation considering $\ S$ to be the distance to be covered i.e.$\ \frac {h}{3}$

That would give us, $$\ \frac {h}{3} = \sqrt{2 g (\frac {2 h}{3})} t + \frac {1}{2}gt^2 $$

Solving this quadratic in  $\ \sqrt h$ would give you the value of  $\ h$ which is the total height. Which comes out to be around 23.42m

I too seriously hope someone comes out with an easier method to solve this!